# Can I create App Delegate file in my project?

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch

I have my ipad code created programmatically not using nib.I converted my ipad app to universal app as follows:

> Choose the project target(the blue one on the sidebar). Summary -> iOS
>   Application Target -> set Devices to Universal.

Now I want to launch different app delegate for iphone and different app delegate for ipad.There is already one app delegate for ipad, now I want to create different app delegate for iphone so that in main.m I can launch different app delegate based on device(ipad & iphone).So my question is, can I create different app delegate, if yes then how?

Comment: why you want to do that?

Comment: Just for more understanding of universal app.Why?

Comment: you dont need to have 2 app delegates, you only need one for universal apps, and then you create different xibs for iphone and ipad

Comment: I am not using nib.I want to do it programmatically.

Comment: you dont have to do it via xib. you can just instantiate your view controller any legal way.

Comment: I did using xib but wanted to learn how this can achieve programmatically so.

Comment: How to create more than one or new Appdelegate file ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in the projects `main.m`

you could do something like

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    @autoreleasepool {

        NSString *appDelegateName;
        if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone){
            appDelegateName =  NSStringFromClass([AppDelegateIPhone class]);
        } else {
            appDelegateName =  NSStringFromClass([AppDelegateIPad class]);
        }
        return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, appDelegateName);
    }
}
```

But IMO you should not do it.

Instead doi it as apple does it to, in app delegate load different view controllers or different XIBs.

```
@implementation AppDelegate

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    self.window = [[[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]] autorelease];
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone) {
        self.viewController = [[[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewController_iPhone" bundle:nil] autorelease];
    } else {
        self.viewController = [[[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewController_iPad" bundle:nil] autorelease];
    }
    self.window.rootViewController = self.viewController;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}



@end
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply.But I know how to launch app delegate based on device.My question is how to create app delegate AppDelegateIPhone?As I already told you, I am not using nib.

Comment: what do u mean by create them? it is just a normal class.

Comment: have a look at the existing AppDelegate. it is a subclass of UIResponder and conforms to the UIApplicationDelegate.

Comment: fixed a small bug in my example.

Comment: and additionally: as I told you, it doesnt matter, for this example, if you use xibs or not.

Comment: Yes I know this example doesn't matter whether I am using xib or not but I wanted to do it this way to learn programmatically.and I thought there might be any other way to create App delegate as we create cell or tableview so asked.

Comment: there should be never a need to create 2 app delegates. use different view controllers, views or xibs instead.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do this through the XIB for your App.  By default, the AppDelegate is assigned by the connection between the `MainWindow.xib` (or whatever your main XIB file is called)'s File Owner and the delegate outlet.  If you used the converter, then the `MainWindow~ipad.xib` should have a similar outlet, which also currently points to the same delegate.   If you want them to be different, create a new AppDelegate subclass and assign it to the outlet in the `~ipad` version of the XIB and it should be the equivalent of calling UIApplicationMain without having to do that manually.

Answer (score 0):

You don't even need to worry about the "appDelegateName" variable there.  Just call return as shown here:

```
  int main(int argc, char *argv[])
  {
      @autoreleasepool {

          if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad){
              return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([AppDelegate_iPad class]));
          } else {
              return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([AppDelegate_iPhone class]));
          }

       }
   }
```