# xcode not creating different app Delegate for universal app

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, ipad

i am totally new to `iphone` and i am trying to create a universal app.

Now I am creating an empty application. According to all tutorials , by checking `universal` option it should auto create `appdelegates` for both iphone and ipad.

But all i can see is only `one appdelegate` . Kindly tell me how can i create both.

Best Regards

Comment: http://www.kotancode.com/2011/04/05/ios-universal-apps/ here, according to the tutorial, it shows 3 diff appdelegates, I am getting only one

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Brayden is correct in answering that you almost *never* need multiple app delegates.  All the delegate usually does is handle the moments when the application launches, suspends or terminates.  Back in the days when iPhones ran iOS 4.0, and iPads ran iOS 3.2, you might need very different code in the delegate because only iOS 4.0 supported multitasking.  Those days are long gone, and your delegate should probably act the same on all devices.

Yes, you sometimes do reach a point where your program must behave differently on iPhone and iPad.  Check the idiom *at that time and no earlier*.  Otherwise you're just duplicating code to no purpose.

My most recent app contains almost no special checks for iPhone or iPad.  It doesn't even use different XIBs.  Instead, my custom views implement `layoutSubviews` to fill the space available.

That said, once you understand app delegates, maybe you will find a situation where you need them to be different.  If you are absolutely certain that your iPhone and iPad behavior will be so wildly divergent, you will need to:

1. Manually create a new class (preferably inheriting from the existing `AppDelegate` class)
2. In your `main.m`, send the class name of your new delegate to `UIApplicationMain` depending on the idiom.

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11135796/1318452) to "Can I create App Delegate file in my project?" to see the changes to `main.m`.

Comment: ok, just last thing. ofc i have diff resolution images for ipad and iphone. I have checkd xib for ipad while making xib file. Now how am i suppose to control both iphone and ipad images with the above code?

Comment: The code discussed above has nothing to do with XIB files or images.  You do not need it.  The only time you might need it is if you find yourself making *many* idiom checks in your single app delegate.

Comment: If you created a universal application, you should find that your existing app delegate contains an `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` method.  This should already check the current idiom and load the XIB file for the appropriate view controller.  If it does not, please edit your question to include the source code for this method.  You need similar code in any other place where you push a view controller or display one modally.

Answer (score 3):

You really should only be using one AppDelegate for a Universal application.  You can use this to share common things that you'll do in there.  What exactly do you need multiple AppDelegates for?  If you need to do something specific to a device type (i.e. - iPhone or iPad) then you can do a ternary expression like below:

(UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad) ? NSLog(@"iPad") : NSLog(@"iPhone");

Comment: according to sample codes etc, I have seen that all apps have two folders named as iphone and ipad with same code but different appdelegat files. Similary this tutorial above is saying the same. Kindly tell me if its a bug or its as is. and i don't need two appdelegates?

Comment: Every universal application I have done has been based off of one AppDelegate.  There really is no need to have multiple delegate files that do the exact same thing.